# Android Null Button

Tags: android, button

What might be the reasons why the button is NULL?

```
Button press;
//...

press = (Button) findViewById (R.id.enter);

if (press != null)
press.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I checked the manifest, the xml file, the code... I don't have any duplicate of R.id.enter, still the button is NULL... It all happened after I introduced a new Activity...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    press = (Button) findViewById (R.id.enter);

    if (press != null)
    press.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

the XML here (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gift2"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/enter"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="415dp"
android:background="@drawable/pattern"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="Open your box now!"
android:textSize="20sp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you setContentView with your layout ?

Comment: submit your oncreate and the layout xml

Comment: What is "this" in press.setOnClickListener(this); line?

Comment: i did. this is the current Activity , which implements OnClickListener. but the problem is that press == NULL

Comment: It's possible the auto-generated `R.java` file may be out of sync. Use Project -> Clean to force regeneration and see if that helps.

Comment: put the code for onClickListener too

Comment: thank you, it worked.... i cleaned the project...so sorry.. thankss

Comment: @Madrugada: I've expanded my comment to an answer for future reference to others who might read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the auto-generated `R.java` file has somehow got out of sync or has invalid values in it.

In this case, `R.id.enter` may no longer be valid and as a result `findViewById(R.id.enter)` can no longer find a valid object to return.

If using Eclipse, try using "Project -> Clean..." - this will delete all auto-generated files and re-create them.